handle calling function exported from custom hook inside a useEffect reactjs
I have the following function which is used in multiple components to refresh a token:
// useRefresh is a custom hook
const refresh = useRefresh()

I have the following useEffect that should only really run on mount:
useEffect(() => {
    const handleRefresh = async () => {
        if (!tokenExpired || !isOpen) return
        const token = await refresh()
        tokenRef.current = token
    }

    const fetchStories = async () => {
        if (isOpen === false) return

        try {
            const result = await axiosPrivate.get(`${BASE_URL}/api/users/stories/${userId}`, {
                headers: { "x-auth-token": tokenRef.current },
            })
            dispatch(setUserStories({ userId, stories: result?.data?.stories }))
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
            return
        }
    }

    const handleMount = async () => {
        await handleRefresh()
        await fetchStories()
        setIsLoading(false)
    }
    handleMount()
}, [isOpen, dispatch, axiosPrivate, userId, tokenExpired, refresh])

The problem I have is that this effect is ran in an infinite loop. this is due to the refresh function being recreated again and again.
I don't want to wrap useCallback around the refresh function inside the custom hook as the refresh function is consumed in numerous components. I tried extracting the handleRefresh function outside the useEffect, and wrapped it inside a useCallback with empty dependency array, however I got a warning saying refresh is missing dependency to useCallback, and when I add it, the function is recreated on every render, defeating the purpose.
Any ideas on how to fix this issue? Thanks.

“I don't want to wrap useCallback around the refresh function inside the custom hook as the refresh function is consumed in numerous components.” I think this probably is the right solution. I don’t understand your explanation for why you don’t want to do it. In any case, this will need to be solved in that custom hook, so please include it in the question.

@TimMoore Because useCallback has an overhead I don't really need it when using refresh in other contexts. Is this the only way to really fix this problem? Is there no other potential solutions?

@TimMoore For example, I found solutions which save the refresh function into a ref like: const refreshFunc = useRef(refresh) and then you can use refreshFunc.current to access the function for example

If you don’t need the solution to apply to all uses of the hook, then a solution outside the hook makes more sense, I agree.

@TimMoore Ok great. But what other potential solutions could there be for this scenario? I listed one above, however after doing some research, I found that it was considered bad practice.

Does const refresh = useMemo(useRefresh, []); work for you?

@TimMoore would the dependency array not need useRefresh as a dependency to useMemo or could i leave the dependency array empty in this instance?

@TimMoore You cant do what you're suggesting. you get an error as you can't use a hook within another

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
